# Regex for Configuration files

Tags: c#, regex, configuration

I am planning a simple configuration file layout like

```
# commentary line
setting1 = some string
setting2 = 123
setting3=whatever
```

Now i want to write a regular expression (in C#.NET) that will be able to read that config file. My attempt is

```
!(\#)(.*)\s=\s(.*)
```

My goal is to

- Ignore commented lines (`!(\#)`)
- Leave formatting to the user (`\s=\s`)

Is that correct or am I doing it wrong, if it's wrong, how would it be done?

Comment: What key names are allowed (letters, numbers (not first) and _). Yes? ANd values can be whatever?

Comment: Names and Values will be parsed as strings, so they basically can be anything.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with a regular expression? It's overkill.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using the standard XML configuration support offered by the .NET Framework?

Comment: Chris Taylor: XML is overkill for my purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
^([a-zA-Z_]\w*)\s*=\s*([^#]+?)$
```

[image]

This works to names which may consist of letter, number and _ (and can't start with number). Flag 'm' (multiply lines) is required (for ^ and $ work)

P.S.I've tried on JS online regex evaluator - but I think regex are the same in C# (may be some changes you should do)

P.P.S.
I see in C# you can give name to match groups in regular expression. I've found some C# code that make similar things (what you need - i think): (here is another regex - with other name-rules and without # comment support - You should change regex to yours)

```
    Regex re = new Regex(@"(?<key>^[a-zA-Z_][\w]*)\s*=\s*(?<value>\w+$)",
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    Match match = re.Matches(str)[0];
    // get pair from line
    string option_name = match.Groups["key"].Value;
    string option_value = match.Groups["value"].Value;
```

Comment: `\w` matches letters, digits, and underscores, so your first parenthesized group can be simplified to `\w+`. But this won't fit OP's requirement that name "basically can be anything" as it doesn't allow spaces or symbols in the name. And this doesn't ignore lines starting with `#`.

Comment: You see - there are matching brackets () there in regex. Sorry, I don't know C# but you can get values from the matching brackets. Brackets #1 is name and brackets #2 is value

Comment: It's not comfortable to add some code in comments, So I added `P.P.S` in my answer post

Comment: @Joe White. Yeap, sorry. \w matches underscore, so it may be simplified

Answer (score 2):

Name value pairs are not that complicated. There is no need to bring regular expressions into this. All you need is a foreach loop for the lines in the file (which you have anyway). Then a simpile if statment checking that the line doesn't start with a
comment indicator, followed by splitting the string based on equals. Regular expressions are cool, but sometimes they make things more complicated. Now you have two problems.

Comment: Don't forget to strip leading and trailing whitespace from both the name and value.

Comment: And use the overload of String.Split that lets you specify the maximum number of substrings to return, and set it to 2. The value could include equal signs, after all.

Comment: Totally agreed. Just going for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using a regular expression, this one should do the job:

```
^([^#][^\s=]+(?:\s+[^\s=]+))\s*=\s*(.*)
```

It won't match any line that starts with `#`. If it does match, the first matching group will be the name (without trailing spaces -- that's what the nested, non-capturing group is for; I think I correctly optimized it to prevent backtracking). The second matching group will be the value, without leading spaces.

I believe this should fit your criterion that names "basically can be anything"; it should match anything except trailing spaces and `=`. And it should match any value, including values that contain `=`. But I haven't tested this to confirm the edge cases, so make sure to write lots of unit tests to make sure it works correctly with a variety of inputs.

And, of course, be aware that this will be both slower, and more complicated, than just [doing the string parsing directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612959/regex-for-configuration-files/5613061#5613061).

Answer (score 0):

Try sth like this:
 ^\s*(?:([^#\s=]+)\s*=\s*([^#]+)(#.*)?)|(#.*)$
If it does';t match line is invalid -> error in config file.
1st and 2nd matching group -> key -> value
Chop whitespaces at the end of value
3rd end of line commnet
4th whole line commnet
What with blak lines?